# Доступ к базе данных MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Hi, Форумчане!

Может ли кто-нибудь ответить на вопрос:
Создана база данных SQL, Добавлена в нее таблица, Вставлено несколько строк в таблицу
Добавлена группа пользователей ([BUILTIN\Пользователи]), добавлен пользователь с правами и ролью db_owner. Любые попытки добавить этот источник данных в проект на C# (Выбор подключения Microsoft SQL Server Database File, выбран тот же сервер, который был подключен при создании базы) упирается на сообщение: "У вас нет разрешения на открытие этого файла". Это сообщение выдается как при выборе Use Windows Authentication, так и при выборе Use SQL Server Authentication с указанием имени пользователя. Может быть надо установить другие флажки прав и ролей?
Looker

Answer (score 1):

У меня был похожий случай при работе в Windows 7, причина оказалась в том, что надо было запускать от имени администратора (щелкаешь правой кнопкой мыши по ярлыку, выбираешь "Запуск от имени администратора").

Answer (score -2):

Я бы на вашем месте разобрался сначала как это работает и накодил подключение вручную а уже только потом использовал встроенные средства среды разработки.